# error- Each column has to have a unique name when you’re returning the query

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, t-sql, reporting-services

I am trying to run reporting services with below SQL query

```
select ca.callingpartynumber, ca.originalcalledpartynumber, case
when calledpartylastname is not null then ca.calledpartylastname + ',' + calledpartyfirstname 
else p1.name end,
p1.location, p1.dept, p1.title,
case
when callingpartylastname is not null then ca.callingpartylastname + ',' + callingpartyfirstname 
else p3.name end
from calldata.calldetailreport ca
join ps_bc_peoplesource_base p1 on ca.originalcalledpartynumber = replace(p1.bc_int_phone, '-', '')
left outer join ps_bc_peoplesource_base p3 on ca.callingpartynumber = replace(p1.bc_int_phone, '-', '')
where originalcalledpartynumber in (select replace(bc_int_phone, '-', '') internal_modified  from ps_bc_peoplesource_base where bc_lan_id = 'f7c')
--and datetimedisconnect between @startdate  and @enddate --1221
```

I get this error-

> “An item with the same key has already been added.”

Comment: This issue because of there are 2 columns with the same name that you are selecting. Make sure to change the final name & that every column when you do run your statement in Management Studio has a unique name. If two column in two different tables, and you are added them in Select Clause, add ALIAS name for each coilumn

Comment: Have you tried providing an explicit alias to your 2 `case ... end` statements?  `case ... end as <alias name>`.

Comment: Thanks! However Now I get an error which says- "the value expression for text box 'finalcalledpartynumber' refers to the field 'finalcalledpartynumber'. Report items can only refer to the current database scope....' What does this mean? Again thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

You are missing Column Alias for Two Case Statement in Your SELECT query. As SSRS uses only the column name as the key, not table + column, so it was choking.

[Refer Here](http://arcanecode.com/2010/07/30/ssrs-quick-tip-an-item-with-the-same-key-has-already-been-added/) And [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911819/an-item-with-the-same-key-has-already-been-added-error-on-ssrs-when-trying-to) And [Here also](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/sqlserver/en-US/4217aeaa-6e3c-438f-a1ff-4a1ab8e389a9/an-item-with-the-same-key-has-already-been-added)

```
SELECT ca.callingpartynumber, ca.originalcalledpartynumber, 
    CASE WHEN calledpartylastname IS NOT NULL  
            THEN ca.calledpartylastname + ',' + calledpartyfirstname 
         ELSE p1.name END AS calledpartylastname,
    p1.location, 
    p1.dept, 
    p1.title,
    CASE WHEN callingpartylastname IS NOT NULL 
            THEN ca.callingpartylastname + ',' + callingpartyfirstname 
        ELSE p3.name END AS callingpartylastname
    ...
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks!
However Now I get an error which says-
"the value expression for text box 'finalcalledpartynumber' refers to the field 'finalcalledpartynumber'. Report items can only refer to the current database scope....' What does this mean?
Again thanks so much!

Comment: This error because you are referring to this 'finalcalledpartynumber' but this column does not exist in current scope/dataset/region. This field is not in your above stated queryso it means you have somehow another query also