# Same Key Already Added error for Unknown time intervals

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am getting error `System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added` while executing following code.

The problem is Sometimes i get this error after 1 hour since program start, sometimes in 5 minutes. It depends.

I try to explain all details and couldn't find the reason for that.

```
 public void getWE()
    {
        if (uceTopActivity.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            if (dtTopAll.AsEnumerable().Any() == true)
            {
                maxDate = dtTopAll.AsEnumerable().Max(z => z.Field<DateTime>("SAMPLE_TIME"));
            }

            var isFull = (dtTopAll.AsEnumerable().Where(l => l.Field<DateTime>("SAMPLE_TIME") == maxDate && l.Field<double>("WAITS") != 0)).Any();

            if (isFull == true)
            {
                var dt1 = (from dr1 in dtTopAll.AsEnumerable()
                           where dr1.Field<DateTime>("SAMPLE_TIME") == maxDate && dr1.Field<double>("WAITS") != 0
                           group dr1 by dr1.Field<string>("Event") into g
                           select new
                           {
                               Event = g.Key,
                               WAITS = g.Sum(z => z.Field<double>("WAITS"))
                           }).ToDataTable();

                ugWaitEvent.DataSource = dt1;

                ugWaitEvent.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns[1].Header.Caption = "Waits (ms/s)";
                ugWaitEvent.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns[0].Width = 190;
                ugWaitEvent.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns[1].SortIndicator = SortIndicator.Descending;
            }
            else
            {
                ugWaitEvent.DataSource = null;
            }

        }
    }
```

Here is the snapshot of the error;
[image: Error]

And It has 3 exception. How can i use these exceptions tabs to get which function and which form control gets the error ;

[image: Error: Translated - An item with the same key has already been added]

Then when i search for Dictionary Word i got below lines on its Designer.cs;

```
global::System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<object, global::System.Data.IDbConnection> revertConnections = new global::System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<object, global::System.Data.IDbConnection>();

global::System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<global::System.Data.DataRow, global::System.Data.DataRow> traversedRows = new global::System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<global::System.Data.DataRow, global::System.Data.DataRow>();
```

Comment: Which line is throwing that exception? Are you **sure** it is the probably line?

Comment: @mjwills .net doesn't show the line. Just throws an error like this.

Comment: @doctorcesar: Are you sure? What does the stack trace say? If you debug it where does it break? Its very rare to be unable to tell the line that is breaking in your own code.

Comment: @Chris I mean, it shows the line in program.cs not in the above function. and program.cs only has the line 'Application.Run(new Login());'

Comment: @Chris added the error ss in question

Comment: @mjwills Edited question with error picture. Its turkish but says 'An item with the same key has already been added'

Comment: While in Debug use Exceptions window to find ArgumentException and check the box next to it, so that it breaks where it's thrown.

Comment: @Gerino yes, its checked already.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/3912007/34092 and https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/27884344/Error-An-item-with-the-same-key-as-already-been-added.html . Your SQL likely has two columns named the same thing.

Comment: @mjwills nope. Columns are not duplicate.

Comment: Create a `try-catch(Exception ex)` around the `Application.Run`, catch the exception and show the stack trace by giving us the content of `ex.ToString()`.

Comment: @MartinMulder i did what you want, but still gives me same error as screenshot.

Comment: Perhaps. But I would like it if you give us the complete exception, including the stack trace (sorry if I was a bit vague about that).

Comment: @MartinMulder Now it gives me same error with the different function. I edited my whole question with the screen shot.

Comment: @Gerino Edited question.

Comment: Search your code for the word `Dictionary` and include the source code for any file that includes that word.

Comment: @mjwills You want me to search for 'Dictionary' words for whole entire solution ? I did and the above function's designer have it. Then what should i do ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Argument Exception "Item with Same Key has already been added"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26516825/argument-exception-item-with-same-key-has-already-been-added)

Comment: If you (temporarily) comment out the lines in the designer file starting with `DebuggerNonUserCode`, does that help you identify where the exception is occurring?

Answer (score 0):

You have code that interacts with one of the following two variables:

```
global::System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<object, global::System.Data.IDbConnection> revertConnections

global::System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<global::System.Data.DataRow, global::System.Data.DataRow> traversedRows
```

That code attempts to add the same key more than once. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/26516900/34092 .

Comment: I don't use the dictionary, control automatically adds in the designer.

Comment: Are you able to show us the source code of the designer so we can assist?